# Resource to Download Android Application Themes/Styles?

Tags: android, download, styles, themes

Is there a resource to download themes and/or styles for the Android development enviroment so I can use them in my application?

Thanks

Comment: Perfect good question. Clear enough for any plant to understand. Sad that those guys keeps closing what they consider irrelevant.

Comment: After a real long search, I stumbled to this website which has the best ready made codes available on Github.com

I hope this helps anyone out there, if it did upvote this comment.

[Awesome Android Codes](http://snowdream.github.io/awesome-android/)